# Generate meta data for OAM SSO using SAML2.0

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, metadata, saml-2.0

I have asp.net web application which needs to be implemented SSO with OAM by using SAML2.0. Our client has asked to provide certificate & metadata of application. But I don't know how will I generate metadata for my application. I found [this](https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php) tool to generate metadata but not sure about what inputs it is asking for.